# Where to use Property or function in Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I don't know where to use property or functions. Can you please explain me in detail about the hasCellphone is a function or property here. And when it can be property or function. What should we use ? 
enable: hasCellphone or 
enable: hasCellphone()
 and why so.

```
<input type='checkbox' data-bind="checked: hasCellphone" />
I have a cellphone

Your cellphone number:
<input type='text' data-bind="value: cellphoneNumber, enable: hasCellphone" />

<script type="text/javascript">
var viewModel = {
    hasCellphone : ko.observable(false),
    cellphoneNumber: ""
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have set yourself, `hasCellphone` as `observable`, it is an observable. And as the official document:

> Observables are functions. The actual value and subscribers to the observable are cached internally by the function. You set an observable’s value by passing the new value as the only argument to the function and you read the value by passing no arguments.

And about using observables without or with `()` :

> However, in a binding if you use an observable in an expression, then you need to reference it as a function. Likewise, in code you typically need to reference your observables as functions, unless you actually want to pass the observable itself (not the value).

You can take a look at the following article:

[10 Things to Know About KnockoutJS on Day One](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/06/10-things-to-know-about-knockoutjs-on.html)